# Replacing [InnerHTML] code with another

Tags: angular

How to replace `[innerhtml]` line of code with other to allow all user-defined properties in angular 4 ?

`[ng...]="..."` ? `[innerHTML]="..."` ?

When I wanted to insert any user-defined files it did not allow me to do it.

Comment: Just post your code that you have tried.

Comment: What kind of code you need to be replaced with?

Comment: Response which is coming from the service the innerHTML which is not allowing me to pass user defined properties.It is allowing only html tags so how can I pass user defined long with the html by replacing innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

```
<div class="any">{{htmlContent}}</div>
```

**Solution 2:**

```
<div class="any" [innerHtml]="htmlContent"></div>
```

**Solution 3:**

```
<div class="any" innerHtml="{{htmlContent}}"></div>
```

Comment: I have tried above solutions but they are not working. Is there any solutions that I can replace innerHTML to allow user defined and html's

Comment: Please watch the URL :-https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b